# Passwordless sftp upload commands not executed using a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, sftp

I have made the sftp password less using the ssh -t key_gen option and the prompt for password does not appear anymore but when I write the commands to be executed on the sftp session like the following in the shell script and execute it they are not executed instead i just get the prompt of sftp

```
#!/bin/sh

username=$1
ipaddr=$2
external_path=$3
extension=$4

sftp $username@$ipaddr
cd $external_path
get *.$extension
exit 

Result

sftp>
```

and nothing else

Could you please tell how this can be achieved, also the expect utility is there on my machine but the sftp does not support the -b option

Thanks,
Priyanka

Answer (score 2):

sftp username@ipaddress will have sftp enter interactive mode. (Thats why you get an sftp style prompt)

[sftp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp)

Since you are using sftp programmability, you want to use it in non interactive mode.

```
sftp $username@$ipaddr:$external_path/filename
#this would work except you need your wildcard * to be expanded

echo "get *" | sftp $username@$ipaddr:$external_path/
#This will work since you are piping the command get * into sftp. 
#* gets expanded by sftp and matching files in $external_path
#Are transfered to your current directory.
```